# How can I load data from an external drive into a Jupyter notebook on MacOs?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have running code in my home directory in Jupyter notebook. I'd like to import some data from an external drive, as the data is too large to be stored on my local drive. I am unable to import this data into my notebook.

Comment: Is the remote drive mounted on your machine? Can you browse to it using Finder? Are you trying to read data from Google Drive, DropBox or http? Add some more info about the type and locaiton of the external drive. Thanks!

Comment: Yes I can browse to it using Finder

Answer (score 0):

If you can browse to the data using Finder, you should be able to load the data into your Jupyter notebook.

Your code to open a file in your notebook probably looks something like this:

`with open("data.txt","r") as dataFile:`

You need to replace `data.txt` with the path to the file you want to open.

One way to get the path name is to navigate to the file in Finder and then drag the file into your Terminal. The path to the file will then be pasted into the command prompt of the Terminal.

The path may look something like this:  `/Volumes/Remove/Data/bigfile.txt`

You can also navigate to the file using the `cd` command in the Terminal.

You may even be able to drag the file directly into your Jupyter notebook to get the path.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Theres a neat trick on mac, If you open up a terminal, and finder and drag the file from finder into the terminal it will write out the path to that file for you in terminal. Then copy/paste the path into your code as mentioned here.